# Setting passenger with Apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, ruby-on-rails-3

I am setting up a new server which I intend to host multiple Ruby on Rails applications on.

The server is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I have set the Apache virtual hosts up so each application has it's own sites-available configuration file (pointing at the Rails public directory). I have then made a symbolic link from `sites-enabled/(CONFIG FILE HERE)` to `sites-available/(CONFIG FILE HERE)`.

**Sites Available**

```
root@HAH-UBUNTU-GER /etc/apache2/sites-available # ls
default  default-ssl  application1.com  application2.com
```

**Sites Enabled (Symbolic links)**

```
root@HAH-UBUNTU-GER /etc/apache2/sites-enabled # ls
000-default  application1.com  application2.com
```

More information on the symbolic links:

```
root@HAH-UBUNTU-GER /etc/apache2/sites-enabled # ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2012-05-04 11:41 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 2012-05-04 12:28 application1.com -> ../sites-available/application1.com
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 2012-05-04 12:09 application2.com -> ../sites-available/application2.com
```

I have uploaded all of the Rails application files to `/var/www/vhosts/application1.com` and made sure the Apache configuration file is pointed at the public directory.

Bundler, ruby gems etc. works but I can't get Passenger to load the application.

As usual, I have set the server up using a bash script which contains the following section which relates to the Passenger installation:

```
# Install and setup the Apache Passenger Module
yes '' | sudo /usr/local/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module

# Add the Passenger config to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
sudo cat > /etc/apache2/httpd.conf << HTTPD_CONF
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-      3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
HTTPD_CONF
```

The full virtual host configuration file for application1.com is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName application1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/application1.com/public
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/application1.com/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
```

If it makes a difference, I am accessing the website by editing my hosts file to point the server IP address at the individual domains.

When I visit the domain I get a listing of the public directory:

[image: Directory Listing of /public]

I assume I am doing something blindingly obviously wrong but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

For more information the full bash script I use is here: https://raw.github.com/deanperry/onelineserver/master/ruby192.sh

**UPDATE**

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Does Apache load the passenger module succesfully? What is the output of `sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`?

Comment: It does look like something's keeping Passenger from running at all. There are a bunch of options; the rational first thing to check is that the module loaded.

Comment: Eh, take out the `Indexes` and replace `Multiviews` with `-Multiviews`.Then restart

Comment: Passenger module doesn't appear in the list of loaded modules (See updated question)

Comment: in which case- run `passenger-install-apache2-module` from the commandline and see what happens

Comment: I've just done that and then added the correct info to apache2.conf but I get '# passenger-status
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger/admin_tools/control_process (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:27:in `<main>' when running passenger-status.

Comment: Did you need to sudo?

Answer (score 4):

[Based on the documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_1_x_or_2_x_but_not_rails_gt_3_x_application), you will need to disable MultiViews on the passenger sites.  Additionally, your `DocumentRoot` should point to the directory containing public--i.e., Passenger [checks to see if the selected directory contains a passenger application](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#application_detection) by checking for `{DocumentRoot}/../config/environment.rb`, so verify that this is correct.

If you're still stumped, [enable logging](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_logging_and_debugging_options) and figure out why it doesn't think you have a Passenger application at that location.

Comment: It appears to be a Passenger installation issue!

Comment: +1 for documentation links and a troubleshooting script, even though the actual problem seems to be elsewhere.